# Rails 3.0.9 Ajax response not executed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I'm using Rails 3.0.9 and jQuery 1.6.2 with jQuery-ujs.

Basically I'd like to ajaxfy my "add to cart" action.

In my view:

```
<td><%= button_to "Add to cart", line_items_path(:coupon_id => coupon, :format => :js), :remote => true %>
```

In my controller:

```
def create
@cart = current_cart
coupon = Coupon.find(params[:coupon_id])
@line_item = @cart.add_coupon(coupon.id)

respond_to do |format|
  if @line_item.save
    format.html { redirect_to(@line_item.cart) }
    format.js   {render :layout => false, :content_type => 'text/javascript'}
    format.xml  { render :xml => @line_item, :status => :created, :location => @line_item }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
    format.js   {render :layout => false, :content_type => 'text/javascript'}
    format.xml  { render :xml => @line_item.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

I've also created a create.js.erb:

```
$("#my_cart").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'layouts/mycart')) %>");
```

to update the cart item number whenever a new item is added.

When I click the "add to cart" button, a JS POST request is sent to the server:

```
    Started POST "/line_items.js?coupon_id=1" for 127.0.0.1 at Thu Aug 18 00:04:31 +0800 2011
  Processing by LineItemsController#create as JS
```

And the response from the server is:

```
Rendered layouts/_mycart.html.erb (5.3ms)
Rendered line_items/create.js.erb (28.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 127ms (Views: 58.7ms | ActiveRecord: 3.0ms)
```

The response's body contains the javascript code to update my cart:

```
$("#my_cart").html("<li id=\"my_cart\"><a href=\"/carts/10\">My cart(1)<\/a>\n<\/li>");
```

However, the web page is not updated. I tried different browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari). But if I manually run this code in Firebug's console, the page got updated. I've googled for a day and tried different solutions. None of them worked me. Could someone solve my problem?

Here's the code generated for button_to:

```
<form method="post" action="/line_items.js?coupon_id=1" data-remote="true" class="button_to"><div><input type="submit" value="Add to cart" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="MdHScf0JVNu2UFXLxuindDvZ5TPBztfMMzv57w1LWX8=" /></div></form>
```

Comment: are you sure that `#my_cart` exists? Try to test it with simple alert

Comment: Can you verify that your javascript file is being executed at all?  Alert or something....Also, can you post the html generated by the button_to erb?

Comment: I tried alert() before and got same result: the javascript is returned from the server but not executed by the browser. I have to manually execute the code in Firebug's console to trigger the alert box.

Answer (score 0):

It looks pretty good as far as I can tell.  Some things I would try in a mystery like this: try taking out the `:format=>'js'` in your button url (I am pretty sure rails knows it is to be formatted for js). Instead of the `respond_to do |format|` block, try getting rid of all that and use `respond_with(@line_item)`
In the top of your controller make sure to specify `respond_to :js`.

I agree with the comments asking to do a simple alert instead of the escape_javascript render partial.

If still not getting anything, switch to a link_to and see if you can get any results.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

I created a new project with the same settings and tried if ajax worked there. Surprisingly, it did. So I concluded that there must be some wrong settings in my project.

And I found and removed this from my `application_controller.rb`:

```
  def set_charset   
      headers["Content-Type"] = "text/html; charset=utf-8" 
  end   

  def configure_charsets   
      response.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/html; charset=utf-8" 
      suppress(ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid) do 
        ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute 'SET NAMES UTF8' 
      end   
  end
```

I copied this code from a tutorial to configure character set. Don't exactly know why it screwed everything up but I could move on with my project now!